# Returning a value with 2 decimal places

Tags: c++

I don't know how to return a value with 2 decimal places because we are not allowed to edit the main where the value is being outputted. The value being returned is 315 but I want to return 315.00

```
//cpp file
double SavingsAccount::calculateInterest()
{
    double x = interestRate*getBalance();  //getBalance() is whatever the balance value is which in this case is $2100
                                           // and interestRate is in this case 0.15
return x;
}
```

Comment: Assuming you are printing to cout: `std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2);`

Comment: You can't. `doubles` don't have decimal places. They have binary places, and the two are incommensurable. You can get *appromately* two decimal places, but you're really better off leaving the value as-is and getting your precision and rounding when *printing.* And you shouldn't be using floating-point for money in the first place.

Comment: I'm not allowed to edit the main file where it is outputed

Comment: There is a difference between the value of a number and the way it is printed.  For example, you could have a variable `double x = 3.14159;` which would be printed as `3.14` with 2 decimal places.  In other words, the number of decimal places refer to the way the number is printed, not to its value.

Comment: Yes, but I'm not allowed to edit the main file where I print x so I am stuck on how to return a value with 2 decimal places

Comment: @WorkMan If you understand what EJP and Sci Prog were talking, then you should understand what you are asking doesn't make sense.  There is no such thing as "a double with 2 decimal places".   You can round it to a number close to it, but you may never got an exact value.